# Imageview changing position when transform is applying?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiimageview, uiviewanimation

I had an IPhone application in which i want to transform my image view to its double size without changing the position of the image view.(i.e. the centre need not be changed)I am doing like this

```
 CGAffineTransform firstTransform = bg.transform;

 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];
 bg.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(bg.transform,2,2);
 [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
 [UIView commitAnimations];
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];
 bg.transform = firstTransform;
 [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

 [UIView commitAnimations];
```

But when transforming its position gets changed.so
Now i am doing like this to do not change the position of the image view.i want the image view to be transformed to the double size on click with an animation like this

[animation on the red button when clicking next](https://loseproof.com/protect1/)

can anybody guide me on this?

Comment: use nested animation using [uiview animateWithduration:completion] blocks.After one animation completes, the completion block is executed.Add the next animation there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the anchor point is set to the centre, bearing in mind when setting the anchor point the value has to be between 0 and 1: 0 being the left/top side and 1 being the right/bottom side. So to set the anchor point to the middle, set it to 0.5 on both the X and Y axis:

```
[itemName.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)];
```

Then when you scale the object, it should scale up from around the centre point.

I also suggest using [animateWithDuration:completion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a). The code will become much simpler:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
    [bg setTransform:CGAffineTransformScale(bg.transform, 2.0, 2.0)];
} completion ^{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
        [bg setTransform:CGAffineTransformScale(bg.transform, 0.5, 0.5)];
    ];
}];
```

Hope this helps you achieve the desired effect!

Comment: In his question: "(i.e. the centre need not be changed)" - also, the link provided showed a circle, so I presumed the centre would be the anchor point

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are not using auto layout. To disable that open your xib, click on first tab in the right panel, uncheck the Use Auto Layout under Interface Builder Document. Screen shot is attached for help.

[image: Auto Layout under Interface Builder Document]